# Isolated storage is cleared after upgrade

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, sql-server-ce, isolatedstorage

I'm developing Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app and I save my data into Isolated Storage. When I updated my app from the store I realised that the app had created new db file. I use SQL Server CE and it's DataContext.

That's my connection string -"Data Source=isostore:/db.sdf;Password='testpass';".

What could be a reason of this problem?

Comment: Did you change platform to Windows Phone 8,1 WinRT?

Comment: No, I want to use Silverlight version